# Does the following diagram (2) commute by the axioms for a direct limit?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, direct-product

Suppose $I,J$ represents any finite subsets of the set of natural numbers $N$ and ($∏_{i∈I}A_i,φ_{JI})_{i\subset j\subset N}$ be a directed set. Suppose, also that the the direct limit $(A,\varphi_I)_{I\subset N}$ of the system exists.
My question is:

Let $\varphi:∏_{i∈N}A_i \to A$ and $\lambda:∏_{i∈N}A_i \to Y$ be maps and
Suppose, $\varphi_I:∏_{i∈I}A_i \to A$, and $\lambda_I:∏_{i∈I}A_i \to Y$ be the restrictions of $\varphi$ and $\lambda$, respectively. Then, by the definition of direct limit, there exists a unique map $\gamma:A\to Y$ s.t $\gamma \circ \varphi_ I =\lambda_I$ for every finite subset of $N$ (Please see fig 1)

Does it follow from this that $\gamma \circ \varphi=\lambda$? (Fig 2).

Are there any deductions for the commutativity of maps from the commutative diagrams of directed system and direct limits, in the literature ?

[image]

Comment: Note that in a general category such 'restrictions' don't necessarily exist or aren't well-defined.

Comment: The object $A$ is a direct limit over just the part of the diagram indexed by $I$ right?  In that case you should label it $A_I$.  If you change the set $I$ then the object that you get as a direct limit will change as well.  The map $\gamma$ should also be labeled with $I$ because the domain of $\gamma_I\colon A_I \to Y$ depends on the object whose universal property you are using to get the existence of $\gamma_I$.  Given that, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Jim No!, the direct system is defined as: $(∏_{i∈I} A_i,φ_{JI})_{i⊂j⊂N}$. It means the objects in this category are $∏_{i∈I} A_i$ rather than just the $A_i$'s, and the directed set is $D$={I: I is a finite subset of natural number} and the order is inclusion.

Comment: @PrinceThomas: Ah, I misunderstood your notation.  In that case how are you defining your transition maps?  How do you get, for example, a map $A_1 \to A_1 \prod A_2$?  Is it just an arbitrary choice of a map?

Comment: @Jim, these transition maps are the canonical inclusions by fixing the elements $e_i$ from each $A_i$, say $a_1$ will be mapped on $(a_1,e_2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With transition and restriction maps defined as you did in the comments then it is not the case that $\gamma\circ\phi = \lambda$ necessarily holds.

For example, in the category of sets the colimit $A$ is equal to the subset of $\prod_{i \in \mathbb N} A_i$ consisting of those $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ for which $a_i = e_i$ holds for all but finitely many $i$.  To define a map $\phi\colon\prod_{i \in \mathbb N}A_i \to A$ whose restriction to any $\prod_{i \in I}A_i$ is $\phi_I$ we simply define $\phi$ to be the identity on the subset $A$ and for those tuples not in the subset we can define their image however we please.  In particular, this means there are **many** maps $\phi\colon\prod_{i \in \mathbb N}A_i \to A$ with the property that the restrictions agree with the $\phi_I$.

Now let $\phi, \lambda\colon\prod_{i \in \mathbb N}A_i \to A$ be two **different** maps whose restriction to any $\prod_{i \in I}A_i$ agrees with $\phi_I$.  The map $\gamma\colon A \to A$ we get from the universal property is simply the identity map, so the equation $\gamma\circ\phi = \lambda$ reduces to $\phi = \lambda$, but this false!  We explicitly chose $\phi$ and $\lambda$ to be different.